# Elephas-- could not install with pip

Tags: python, pip, elephas

I'm  trying to install elephas with pip install but I get the following error

```
> ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\patri\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\armano project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\patri\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\armano project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "c:\users\patri\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\armano project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\patri\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\armano project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "c:\users\patri\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\armano project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "c:\users\patri\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\armano project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 384, in resolve
    raise ResolutionTooDeep(max_rounds)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionTooDeep: 2000000
```

Comment: I'm using pip 21.1.1

Comment: [This](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9841) is similar so you might try downgrading pip - `pip install --upgrade pip=21.0.1` and retry installing elephas.